# embarrasing problem with #include in C

Tags: c, include

Could you please solve my problem? looking at the code, it is self explanatory:

a.h:

```
#include"c.h"
void a()
{
    printf("I am in a\n");
}
```

c.h:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void a();
void b();
```

main.c:

```
#include"c.h"

main()
{
    a();

}
```

and `gcc main.c` will give me:

```
/tmp/ccuaiUEA.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `a'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you please help me in a way that file extensions (.h and .c) remain unchanged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to rename `a.h` to `c.c` and then build and run like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c c.c -o main
$ ./main
```

Explanation: your `a.h` is a *source file*, not a *header*, so it need to have a `.c` suffix, not `.h`. Its corresponding header is `c.h` so by convention it should be named `c.c`. When you build your executable you need to compile and link both `main.c` and `c.c` source files, which is why they are both included in the `gcc` command line.

Answer (score 4):

Including `a.h` from `main.c` will "fix" your issue, but that's just not recommended.

You should put your code in `.c` files, not in headers.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing includes `a.h`. You need to add `#include "a.h"` after `#include "c.h"` in `main.c`.

By the way, why do you put the function definition in a header file?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, never define anything in .h files. Don't put variable- or function definitions there. It makes the code messy and hard to read, and you also get countless linker problems on most compilers.

a.h should be a c.c file that includes c.h.

Answer (score 1):

Include `a.h` in `main.c`

The way it is written the content of "a.h", i.e. the function body, is never compiled nor linked to your main program.

But as a rule of thumb, function's **prototypes** should be in header while the function's **definition** should be in C file.